# TypeError: unbound method fight() must be called with Pokemon instance as first argument (got type instance instead)

Tags: python

This is my code:

```
# pokemon1
class Pokemon(object):
    def __init__(self,name,hp,damage):
        self.name = name     
        self.hp = hp        
        self.damage = damage 

    def fight(self,other):
        if(self.hp > 0):
            print("%s did %d damage to %s"%(self.name,self.damage,other.name))
            other.hp -= self.damage
            if (other.hp > 0):
                print("%s has %d hp left" % (other.name, other.hp))
            else:
                print("%s has died" % (other.name))
            return other.fight(self)
        else:
            print("%s wins! (%d hp left)"%(other.name,other.hp))
            return other,self  

class pikachu(Pokemon):
    def __init__(self):
        super(pikachu, self).__init__('pikachu', 100, 10)

class pidgy(Pokemon):
    def __init__(self):
        super(pidgy, self).__init__('pidgy', 200, 12)

#main
import pokemon1

pikachu = pokemon1.pikachu
pidgy = pokemon1.pidgy

p = pokemon1.Pokemon
p.fight(pikachu,pidgy)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call Pokemon(), not Pokemon, in your second-last line to invoke the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Reinderien was right, but I tried your code and found a different problem, you designed the class differently to how you are trying to use it.

This code should work instead:

```
pikachu = pokemon1.pikachu
pidgy = pokemon1.pidgy

pikachu.fight(pidgy)
```